# If return false does not work on Redmine API through kbsali/php-redmine-api

Tags: php, xml, api, redmine, redmine-api

I updated the code with help by @raiserle (thank you).

The code below enables me to show an error message if a user has no right to create an issue or there is connection problem and last but not least if `project_id` is empty or not valid.

However, if the issue has been created I see `SimpleXMLObject`content with the help of `var_dump`.

Here is the code:

```
    // ----------------------------
// Instanciate a redmine client
// --> with ApiKey
$client = new Redmine\Client('http://localhost:8080/redmine/', '210940249ksdjfksdh32');

// ----------------------------
// [OPTIONAL] set the port
// (it will try to guess it from the url)
$client->setPort(8080);

// ----------------------------
$ret = $client->api('issue')->create(array(
    'project_id'        => '',
    'subject'           => $subject,
    'description'       => $description,
    'assigned_to_id'    => $assingto,
    'tracker_id'        => $trackerId,
    'watcher_user_ids'  => $watcherId,
));
if( $ret instanceof SimpleXMLElement ){
    //look in the Object
    var_dump($ret);
}
else{
    if( $ret === true ){
        echo "success";
    }
    else{
       echo "error";
    }
}
```

Now the thing is can I make a simple success message or error messages according to error.

Here are the server responses/returns samples. Server returns with the following error let`s say if I did not provide a subject:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "array"
  }
  ["error"]=>
  string(22) "Subject can't be blank"
}
```

And here is an example of server response if the issues have been created successfully:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (17) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "340"
  ["project"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "9"
      ["name"]=>
      string(26) "Some Project name"
    }
  }
  ["tracker"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Some tracker name"
    }
  }
  ["status"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "New"
    }
  }
  ["priority"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Normal"
    }
  }
  ["author"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "22"
      ["name"]=>
      string(7) "author name"
    }
  }
  ["assigned_to"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Some name"
    }
  }
  ["subject"]=>
  string(16) "test api (xml) 2"
  ["description"]=>
  string(25) "some dummy content"
  ["start_date"]=>
  string(10) "2014-04-17"
  ["due_date"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (0) {
  }
  ["done_ratio"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["estimated_hours"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (0) {
  }
  ["spent_hours"]=>
  string(3) "0.0"
  ["created_on"]=>
  string(20) "2014-04-17T15:52:07Z"
  ["updated_on"]=>
  string(20) "2014-04-17T15:52:07Z"
  ["closed_on"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (0) {
  }
}
```

**Any help will be much approtiated.** Just guide me to correct way.
Other then that kbsali does not say much about the usage of their code. I do not know if there is a way to get server responses from their codes. I mean obviously code gets server response but I do not know how can I reach it. If anybody figures how that will also solve my problem definitely.

Here is the URL for kbsali redmine-php-api on github:
https://github.com/kbsali/php-redmine-api

Comment: any errors? more information!

Comment: Is the comma after    'tracker_id'         => '3'  necessary?

Comment: @ShaneA.Darr array( 1,2,3,4,); is right!

Comment: No i got no error if every data sent correctly it creates issue on redmine if not obviosly it does not.But no matter what it says error. 
There is nothing more.

Comment: Ok, read my post: I'm think, you use an function as property.
change error_level to all

`error_reporting( E_ALL );`


give this an error?

Comment: Yes the is not necessary i guess but it was on the original code.

Comment: I read your post and i am going to try after i enable error reporting.
And i will write the outcome here. Tahnk you.

Comment: error_reporting( E_ALL ); did not work no errors.
@raiserle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm got to the github - and see this

```
<?php
$client->api('issue')->create(array(
  'project_id'  => 'test',
  'subject'     => 'some subject',
  'description' => 'a long description blablabla',
  'assigned_to' => 'user1',
));
?>
```

you make this

```
<?php
if($client->api('issue')->create === true) { //create is no property, is a function
?>
```

change your code to

```
<?php
$ret = $client->api('issue')->create(array(
  'project_id'     => '13',
  'subject'        => 'test api (xml) 2',
  'description'    => 'test api',
  'tracker_id'         => '3',
));
if( $ret ) {
    //....
}
else{
    //....
}
?>
```

---

I've got the source and extract the code to add an issue, shown at: http://pastebin.com/dXB1c88S

change the if-statement to

```
<?php

if( $ret instanceof SimpleXMLElement ){
    //look in the Object
    var_dump($ret);

    //UPDATE: after see your response object
    if( isset( $ret->error ) ){
        //any error occurred
        //$ret->error takes an message
    }
    else{
        //there is no error: issue successful created 
    }
}
else{
    if( $ret === true ){
        //i do not see... issue is successful created?
        //there is no response?!
    }
    else{
        //return is a string
        //i do not see... issue is successful created?
        //check the string
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I am going to give it try. Thank you.

Comment: `if($client->api('issue')->create === true) {` i coudl not figure out where should i add it.
And this has same with my previous problem.
`<?php
$ret = $client->api('issue')->create(array(
  'project_id'     => '13',
  'subject'        => 'test api (xml) 2',
  'description'    => 'test api',
  'tracker_id'         => '3',
));
if( $ret ) {
    //....
}
else{
    //....
}
?>`
@raiserle

Comment: I include the function to use this
`require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`
Do you think can we find something on that one @raiserle

Comment: this solved my problem.
`if( $ret instanceof SimpleXMLElement ){
    //look in the Object
    //var_dump($ret);
}
else{
    if( $ret === true ){
        echo 'success';
    }
    else{
       echo 'error';
    }
}`
If it does not create new issue it says error but if it does it dumps whole respond so i commented out `var_dumb` now if it creates the issue i see nothing but if it does not gives error.
That was my goal and i almost done it. Thank you so much for your precious helps.

Comment: Ok, but check the SimpleXMLElement. There can be take information about error... e.g. you create an issue whith existing ID or... what ever.. I think, you got the SimpleXMLElement with error information, why not created the issue.

Comment: I did not get the point? Are you saying that check for error codes in server respond? If so it does not bring any error codes. If it fails to create issue `var_dumb` shows an empty string.

Comment: Now i got the point you have made on previous message, ı checked SimpleXMLElement and figured out that if it creates the issue server respond starts with `object(SimpleXMLElement)#8` at all times. And if some error occures there is `["error"]` on the server response.
I think we can do somethings with it? @raiserle

Comment: However server generates error for particular fields for example;
If i do not enter subject server returns with error but if i do not enter project_id it returns with empty string.

Comment: That it's, what i mean. An `SimpleXMLObject` not clearly to say: The ISSUE was created. You can update your question with some information about return/response from server by create an issue with OK, an some errors? This makes easier for me/other to understand the problem, without read all the comments.

Comment: Thx... you can now see... check the returned object, if is the SimpleXMLElement-object `if( $ret instanceof SimpleXMLElement ){
    if( isset( $ret->error ) ){
        //any error occurred
    }
    else{
        //there is no error: issue successful created 
    }
}`

Comment: Yesss completely did what i needed to do. Again thank you so much for your precious helps.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$val = $client->api('issue')->create(array(
    'project_id'     => '13',
    'subject'        => 'test api (xml) 2',
    'description'    => 'test api',
    'tracker_id'     => '3'
));

//Debug
var_dump($val);
echo $val->asXML();

//Once you read the XML's content
$var = (string) $var->someNode->innerNode;
if($var==='whatever_is_the_expected_result')
    echo 'data sent';
else
    echo 'error';
```

Comment: I am going to give it try. Thank you.

Comment: `var_dump($val);` helped me to see if string is empty or an object created, however `if` `else` still not working.
If an error occures `var_dump` returns `string(1) " "` if it creates an object it returns begining with `object(SimpleXMLElement)#8` Can we catch something with that? @Reacen

Comment: @orko: Looks like its returning a `SimpleXMLElement` object. Try this to print its content: `echo $val->asXML();` then you can compare the results and get whatever data you want using `$arr = $var->children('something'); var_dump($arr);` to make sure it's been correctly added.

Comment: `else` is useless: its every time return TRUE,STRING or OBJECT
By compare `if($val)` its ever TRUE!